# end if statement not working wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm manipulating the data to switch places when displayed. The data are on a if structure. The data are divided into three-four I think Category, Dates and Title. The current structure is Category, Date and Title responsively. I want to change it to Date, Title and Category. But I'm having some errors.

PHP CODE:

```
        <?php if ( $displays_date ) { ?>
             <time class="entry-date published" datetime="<?php the_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></time>
             <time class="updated" datetime="<?php the_modified_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php the_modified_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></time>
        <?php } ?>


        <?php if ( $displays_cat ) { ?>
            <span class="entry-category">
                <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
            </span>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( ! is_category() ) { // Do not display category name in category pages  ?>
        <span class="entry-category">
            <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
        </span>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php 
        // Date
        global $ti_option;
        if ( $ti_option['post_item_date'] == '1' ) : 
        ?>
            <time class="entry-date published" datetime="<?php the_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></time>
            <time class="updated" datetime="<?php the_modified_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php the_modified_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></time>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php content_post_item_title(); ?>
```

Tried to do this in this way. It got some errors about the endif.

```
        <?php if ( $displays_date ) { ?>
             <time class="entry-date published" datetime="<?php the_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></time>
             <time class="updated" datetime="<?php the_modified_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php the_modified_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></time>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php 
        // Date
        global $ti_option;
        if ( $ti_option['post_item_date'] == '1' ) : 
        ?>
            <time class="entry-date published" datetime="<?php the_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></time>
            <time class="updated" datetime="<?php the_modified_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php the_modified_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></time>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php content_post_item_title(); ?>


        <?php if ( $displays_cat ) { ?>
            <span class="entry-category">
                <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
            </span>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( ! is_category() ) { // Do not display category name in category pages  ?>
        <span class="entry-category">
            <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
        </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

I'm running this on my WordPress Site.

Answer (score 0):

In the last block of code you are using 'endif'

Try to replace 'endif' on closing bracket:

```
<?php if ( ! is_category() ) { // Do not display category name in category pages  ?>
    <span class="entry-category">
        <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
    </span>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the if statements are not joined together and can be move without changing any codes.

```
        <?php if ( $displays_date ) { ?>
             <time class="entry-date published" datetime="<?php the_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></time>
             <time class="updated" datetime="<?php the_modified_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php the_modified_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></time>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php 
        // Date
        global $ti_option;
        if ( $ti_option['post_item_date'] == '1' ) : 
        ?>
            <time class="entry-date published" datetime="<?php the_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></time>
            <time class="updated" datetime="<?php the_modified_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php the_modified_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></time>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php content_post_item_title(); ?>

        <?php if ( $displays_cat ) { ?>
            <span class="entry-category">
                <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
            </span>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( ! is_category() ) { // Do not display category name in category pages  ?>
        <span class="entry-category">
            <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
        </span>
        <?php } ?>
```